# how to find the mobile device is connected to internet

Tags: android

For my android app need to connect internet to perform some tasks. If there is no internet it stops. Is there is a cord to check the internet connection, so then I can give a message to user to connect the device to internet?

Comment: [Determine if you Have an Internet Connection](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineConnection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need permission to know whether the device is connected to the web or not. This needs to be in your manifest, in the  element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method of **ConnectivityManager** returns a instance that represents the first connected network interface that it can find or `null` if none of the interfaces are connected. Checking if this method returns null should be enough to tell if an internet connection is available.

```
private boolean isDeviceConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfoActive = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfoActive != null && networkInfoActive.isConnected();
}
```

After this you should create an method or put the following code into the `onCreate()` method to show an alert.

```
    if (isDeviceConnected()) {
        // do whatever you want to do
    } else {
        try {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialog
                    .setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alerticon);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Show Dialog: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo i = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

boolean hasConnection = (i != null && i.isConnected() && i.isAvailable());
```

`context` should be a valid `Context` object. For example `Activity`.

Comment: this checks network availabiliity not the internet connectivity.The phone may be connected to wifi with no internet connection